# C++ Inner Class Ctor and Parameters

Tags: c++, list, iterator, listiterator

I am having trouble with creating the ctor for my inner class `ListIterator` inside `List`, I don't know why this isn't working:

```
template<class T, int length>
class List {
public:
    typedef struct Row {
        T data;
        int prev;
        int next;
    } Row;

    class ListIterator {
        typedef ListIterator iterator;
        public:
            ListIterator(int mPos, Row mRow) : pos(mPos) , row(mRow){}
            //methods
        private:
            int pos;
            Row row;
    };

    typedef ListIterator iterator;

    iterator begin() const;
private:
    Row storage[length];
    int startDataIdx = 0;
};

template<class T, int length>
typename List<T,length>::iterator
List<T, length>::begin() const{
    iterator item_iterator(startDataIdx, storage[startDataIdx]);
    return(item_iterator);
}
```

> no matching function for call to 'List::ListIterator::ListIterator(const int&, const Row&)'

I want to create a `ListIterator<T>` which the same `T` as `List` as parameter (obviously because it iterates over the same type of elements as `List` contains), how do I do that?
Would it be better to use `new` in the method `begin()` or leave it as it is (don't use new, whatever advantages that might have)?

Comment: Every standard library container has `iterator` and `const_iterator` inner classes, why do you think it is so?

Comment: So you are telling me that I can't create an `iterator` which has a reference to a row from a `list`?

Answer (score 1):

```
ListIterator(int &mPos, Row* mRow) : pos(mPos) , row(mRow){}
```

The first parameter to the iterator's constructor is a reference to a mutable `int`.

```
List<T, length>::begin() const{
   iterator item_iterator(startDataIdx, ...
```

You are constructing the iterator in a `const` class method. `this` is `const` over here. `startDataIdx` is effectively `const` here, and as I'm sure you understand, you cannot create a non-`const` reference to a `const` object.

Using a reference for a parameter to the iterator, in this case, accomplishes absolutely nothing useful, whatsoever. Just get rid of the reference, and pass in a simple `int`.

Comment: Okay, I edited my question with the working code now, thanks alot! Do you have any ideas on how to fix my other questions?

Comment: Yes, but `Row* mRow` has the same problem and you can't just get rid of the `*`.